# Solution of first order integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Consider
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = \int_{0}^{\infty} y(x)dx = R~~(say) $$
$$ y(0) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)y(x)dx.$$

I want to solve above differential equation.
Here is my try:

$$ y(x) = y(0) e^{-\int_{0}^{x}p(\tau)d \tau} + R \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\int_{s}^{x} p(\tau) d \tau} ds. $$
where $$ R = \int_{0}^{\infty} y(0) e^{-\int_{0}^{x}p(\tau)d \tau} dx + R \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-\int_{s}^{x} p(\tau) d \tau} ds dx $$
$$ y(0) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)y(0) e^{-\int_{0}^{x}p(\tau)d \tau} dx + R \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\int_{0}^{x} e^{-\int_{s}^{x} p(\tau) d \tau} ds dx. $$
Now, I am not able to find $R$ which is independent of $y(0)$ and $y(0)$ which is independent of $R$. Please let me know if it is possible to find solution of this integro-differential equation.

Comment: Are $p$ and $f$ arbitrary functions? You have not specified what they are, so it is unclear what exactly you are doing.

Comment: $p$ and $f$ are continuous functions. Here, I am trying to find solution to given integro-differential equation with initial data in the form of integral involving solution of given differential equations.

Comment: I understand now. In that case, it appear you have two linear equations in two unknown to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$R=y(0)\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\int_0^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}x+R\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^xe^{-\int_s^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}x$$ $$y(0)=y(0)\int_0^{\infty}f(x)e^{-\int_0^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}x+R\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\int_0^xe^{-\int_s^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}x$$ you can rearrange to obtain two linear equations with two unknowns. The former equation is equivalent to $$0=y(0)\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\int_0^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}x+R\left[\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^xe^{-\int_s^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}x-1\right]$$ while the latter is equivalent to $$0=y(0)\left[\int_0^{\infty}f(x)e^{-\int_0^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}x-1\right]+R\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\int_0^xe^{-\int_s^xp(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau}\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}x$$ This can be solved with just elementary algebra, or using matrix algebra. You will get $y(0)$ and $R$ exclusively in terms of $f$ and $p,$ provided suitable integrability conditions for these functions. It depends on the determinant of the corresponding matrix. If the matrix is invertible, then $y(0)$ and $R$ are unique.